# Why is my state not properly rendered in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, redux, firebase-storage

In my project I use ReactJS in combination with redux and firebase.
Creating a thunk to make async calls to firebase and store the data in redux.

When I'm fetching my files from firebase storage.
Using this method:

```
try {
  let list = [];
  await storage
    .ref()
    .child(path)
    .listAll()
    .then((res) => {
      res.items.forEach((item) => {
        storage
          .ref()
          .child(item.fullPath)
          .getDownloadURL()
          .then((urlRes) => {
            list.push({
              name: item.name,
              url: urlRes,
            });
          });
      });
    });

  dispatch(getFileActionSuccess(list));
```

This method works as intended.
It returns an array of files with their url to view/download them.
The problem is when I try to access this object in my state, it returns an empty array.
Even though when checking using Redux Devtools, I can clearly see that after the list was dispatched. And I could see the correct data.

[Devtools image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wijV9.png)

**Note: this is not the real code but a representation**

```
function page() {
  getFiles();


 <filesList/>
 }



function filesList() {
  const files = useSelector((state) => state.files, _.isEqual);

  console.log(files);
 return (..insert render..);
}
```

But when [logging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QbQxY.png) the files. It shows an empty array at first. But when expanding it, it shows the correct data. But it doesn't render it. As I don't understand why it isn't showing like it is supposed to I no longer know what to do and how to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply fetch the data on component mount and component update, and update your state accordingly.

If you’re using React Hooks, you can use React.useState() and give it a dependency. In this case the dependency would be the part of your state which will update upon completion of your HTTP request.